# How do I join my Raspbian server to a VLAN?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, vlan, raspbian

Just so I don't waste anyone's time, I am not looking to join two networks on one network adapter or route between Wi-Fi and Ethernet.

I have a Netgear managed switch. My Raspberry Pi is attached to a port that is tagged with VLAN 10. I just want to provide a static IP address and have the server take part in VLAN 10. I have a Unifi Security gateway that takes care of all the routing between the different VLANs.

I have had this working using Ubuntu 18.04 using Netplan. Without trying to confuse you, this is my Netplan config, which I am trying to duplicate using Raspbian.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bridges:
    br10:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan10 ]
      addresses: [ 192.168.10.20/24 ]
      gateway4: 192.168.10.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - "192.168.10.3"
          - "8.8.8.8"
  vlans:
    vlan10:
      id: 10
      link: eth0
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```